# Tensorflow: GPU Utilization is almost always at 0%

Tags: neural-network, gpu, tensorflow, nvidia, deep-learning

I'm using tensorflow with Titan-X GPUs and I've noticed that, when I run the CIFAR10 example, the `Volatile GPU-utilization` is pretty constant around 30%, whereas when I train my own model, the `Volatile GPU-utilization` is far from steady, it is almost always 0% and spikes at 80/90% before going back to 0%, over and over again.

I thought that this behavior was due to the way I was feeding the data to the network (I was fetching the data after each step, which took some time). But after implementing a queue to feed the data and avoid this latency between steps, the problem persisted (see below for the queuing system).

Any idea?

```
batch = 128 # size of the batch
x = tf.placeholder("float32", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float32", [None, n_classes])

# with a capacity of 100 batches, the bottleneck should not be the data feeding
queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=100*batch,
                  min_after_dequeue=80*batch,
                  dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.float32],
                  shapes=[[n_steps, n_input], [n_classes]])
enqueue_op = queue.enqueue_many([x, y])
X_batch, Y_batch = queue.dequeue_many(batch)

sess = tf.Session()

def load_and_enqueue(data):
    while True:
        X, Y = data.get_next_batch(batch)
        sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={x: X, y: Y})

train_thread = threading.Thread(target=load_and_enqueue, args=(data))
train_thread.daemon = True
train_thread.start()

for _ in xrange(max_iter):
    sess.run(train_op)
```

Comment: How long does `data.get_next_batch` relative to other operations? It seems to be the only only running on CPU, and it may be slowing down the pipeline.

Comment: For a batch of size 128 `get_next_batch` takes approximately 14x more time than `sess.run(train_op)`  to run. However, before beginning the training, I feed the queue with 100 * batch examples, so at least in the beginning I should have some good GPU utilization, no?

Comment: If the training is an order of magnitude faster than the feeding, it is possible that the dequeuing operation is waiting most of the time, meaning the GPU-run part (`train_op`) waits for the CPU-run thread (for `load_and_enqueue`). I am not clear yet what the interplay with the `min_after_dequeue`, though. How about running all on CPU (*i.e.* no thread), and see if the usage is smoother?

Comment: So the problem seems understood now. A solution is probably to pre-process the data, so that feeding is as fast or faster than training. Note that complex models can be way slower...

Comment: Yes it is, thank you. I deleted my comments and will post a proper answer to my question. Thanks again for helping me figure it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After doing some experiments, I found the answer so I post it since it could be useful to someone else.

First, `get_next_batch` is approximately 15x slower than `train_op` (thanks to Eric Platon for pointing this out).

However, I thought that the queue was being fed up to `capacity` and that only after the training was supposed to begin. Hence, I thought that even if `get_next_batch` was way slower, the queue should hide this latency, in the beginning at least, since it holds `capacity` examples and it would need to fetch new data only after it reaches `min_after_dequeue` which is lower than `capacity` and that it would result in a somehow steady GPU utilization.

But actually, the training begins as soon as the queue reaches `min_after_dequeue` examples. Thus, the queue is being dequeued as soon as the queue reaches `min_after_dequeue` examples to run the `train_op`, and since the time to feed the queue is 15x slower than the execution time of `train_op`, the number of elements in the queue drops below `min_after_dequeue` right after the first iteration of the `train_op` and the `train_op` has to wait for the queue to reach again `min_after_dequeue` examples.

When I force the `train_op` to wait until the queue is fed up to `capacity` (with `capacity = 100*batch`) instead of starting automatically when it reaches `min_after_dequeue` (with `min_after_dequeue=80*batch`), the GPU utilization is steady for like 10 seconds before going back to 0%, which is understandable since the queue reaches `min_after_dequeue` example in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: So what was the solution. I am facing the same problem. Knowing that I am running    my code using tf.keras. and my buffer size is 1000 + 4 * batch size.