# Tensorflow timeline shows long pauses between train steps. What is a reason of this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

There are strange pauses in execution process while running train process in tensorflow. What can be reason of this pauses? I've attached  output of timeline for first 20 train iterations[image]

Comment: It is hard to tell without looking at the code but, usually when the GPU is idle, it is because data is being copied to or from the RAM onto VRAM. (device to host or vice versa). Try this out, https://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/, might help.

Comment: One common reason could also be that the preprocessing is bottlenecking your training. You can check the utilisation of the GPU: if the GPU utilisation spikes and is idle between consecutive spikes, it might indicate such bottleneck.

Comment: This question might also be helpful: [Tensorflow: GPU Utilization is almost always at 0%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297581/tensorflow-gpu-utilization-is-almost-always-at-0/38375249#38375249)

Comment: @SouradeepNanda Thank you very much! Your suggestion was really helpful. I've  modified my input pipeline and now it's work fast. Thanks!

Comment: @BiBi yes, the problem was in reading data from hdf5. It was really slow. Now with tfrecords reading data is fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell without looking at the code but, usually when the GPU is idle, it is because data is being copied to or from the RAM onto VRAM. (device to host or vice versa).

Try [TF Records](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) here is a nice [guide](https://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/).